# Is it possible to check if the object is available before Destructuring?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object of values to `Destructure`, But before doing so i would like to check if the object is available,

```
const  { contactno, contactemail } =  this.props.app.user;
```

In this case the object `user` is not available always, Due to this I am getting following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contactno' of undefined.
```

Hence, Is there nay way to check if the object is available before `Destructure`?

Comment: What would you like to happen if it's undefined?

Comment: Destructuring tends to imply that you know exactly what object you're passing in. Otherwise, you should just wrap the whole thing in `if(this.props.app.user) { ... }`

Comment: You can using an if statement. Or default to an empty object `this.props.app.user || {}`

Comment: you can try this way `const  { contactno, contactemail } =  (this.props.app && this.props.app.user) ?this.props.app.user : {} ;`

Comment: @CertainPerformance if the desired object is not available, I don't want to fetch anything, is it possible to check in the single statement itself?

Comment: "fetch"? Destructuring will always assign to variables. If you don't want to create variables given a condition, you'll have to explicitly check that condition in a separate statement

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol if i use If condition and then Destructuring , I am getting an error `Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context`

Comment: @Kishore you can mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using AND and OR operator you can safely destructure object like this.

```
const  { contactno, contactemail } =  (this.props.app && this.props.app.user) || {};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it like below (nested destructuring). If `user` is `undefined` the default to `{}` in destructuring. when user is undefined, the contactno, contactemail also undefined with this.

```
const  { user: { contactno, contactemail } = {} } =  this.props.app;
```

Comment: Please note that this will not work if `user` is set to `null`, `false`, `''` or anything. it will only work if `user` is either `undefined` or `{}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
const  { contactno, contactemail } =  (this.props.app && this.props.app.user) ? this.props.app.user : {} ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the double question mark (nullish coalescing) operator

const  { contactno, contactemail } =  this.props.app.user ?? {};

Reference:
https://sebhastian.com/javascript-double-question-mark/